# expectation of probabilty with a conditioned vector of ones

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have probabiltiy $p$ defined as
$ p = (\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1}{1-x})\mathbb{1}_{x\leq\alpha})+\mathbb{1}_{x>\alpha}$

I'm trying to find the expectation of $p$, what really bothers me is this vector $\mathbb{1}$ which changes it's behavior based on the value of alpha, aka it could be one when ${x\leq\alpha}$, I'm really unable to resolve it's existence.

My current attempt is like this $\mathbb{E(p)}=$

\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1}{1-\mathbb{E(x)}},& \text{if } x\leq \alpha\\
    1,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
I'm also not sure which terms I can use to google such a problem.

Comment: I don't understand what the $1$ with the subscripts means - do you mean to say $p$ will be equal to that expression involving the natural log if $x\leq \alpha$ and that it will be equal to $1$ if $x> \alpha$? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @K.defaoite this 1 is a vector with and element value equals one if the condition is true or 0 otherwise. I'm not sure about the later part of your comment, but this is a vector probability with multiple instances.

Comment: First of all, what is $p$? You are talking of expectation of $p$ as if it is a random variable.